# Getting width size from a hidden element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a small problem, please help me out on this, finding what I'm missing here.
My html code is:

```
<div class="drop-down-menu">
  <div class="innerdrop-down-menu">
    <div id="first-tab-cont">
      <ul id="slider">
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
       </ul>
       <a href="javascript:;" id="back">&lArr;</a>
       <a href="javascript:;" id="forward">&rArr;</a>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS code:

```
.drop-down-menu{ display:none; position:relative; background-color:#FFFFFF; width:100%; height:280px; z-index:2; }
#first-tab-cont{ background-color:#CCC; display:none; width:960px; height:240px; padding:20px; }
#slider{ background-color:#C9F; position:relative; min-width:100%; width:auto; height:240px; font-family: HelveticaNeue; white-space:nowrap; }
#slider li{ background-color:#C03; display:inline-block; margin-right:15px; white-space:nowrap; width:300px; height:240px; }
```

And the current jQuery code is:

```
var Min = 0;
var Max = $("#fifth-tab-cont #slider").width();
var Step = 300;

$("#first-tab-cont #back").click(function(){
    if($("#first-tab-cont #slider").position().left <= Min + Step) {
        $("#first-tab-cont #slider").animate({left: '+=300px'}, Step );
    }
});
$("#first-tab-cont #forward").click(function(){
    if($("#first-tab-cont #slider").position().left >= Max + Step) {
        $("#first-tab-cont #slider").animate({left: '-=300px'}, Step );
    }
});
```

And my question is how can I gett the `slider` width size so I can only scroll left until his dimension?

Comment: hidden-> not in the dom -> not rendered -> no size. You have to render element, to have size.

Comment: You have a deeper issue, when your `#slider` is not hidden, its width ends up being `960px` which is due to its parent element and the `min-width: 100%` css on `#slider`. But your elements within `#slider` add to `1500px`. You basically need to slide the `li`'s rather than `#slider` itself. This Fiddle is an example of a similar behavior: [JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/3jdy44po/)

Comment: but is not scrolling any more if I change it to `#slider li`

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it in fiddle and shared a link getting slider width as a hidden element. we can do it simply using the css property

```
visibility:hidden;
```

Instead of using `display:none;` we can use `visibility:hidden;`  which make jquery to think like the element is there but actually it is hidden and it will pass us the width.

I have given a alert to show the `#slider` width please check it.

http://jsfiddle.net/fzd10zak/2/

Comment: `visibility: hidden` will still affect the layout of other elements on the page. See your edited fiddle demonstrating the issue: [jsfiddle updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/fzd10zak/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$(".yourSlider").get(0).scrollWidth
```

and instead of `display:none` use `width:0px`
The jQuery function will return the actual non-hidden width of the element because the DOM stores the scroll width.

Answer (score 0):

One could make it displayed (`display: block`), but make it transparent (`opacity: 0`). Or show it, get dimensions, and then hide it.

```
var Min = 0,
    $dropDownMenu = $('.drop-down-menu').show(),
    $slider = $("#slider");
    Max = $slider.width(),
    Step = 300;

$dropDownMenu.hide();

$("#back").click(function(){
    if($slider.position().left <= Min + Step) {
        $slider.animate({left: '+=300px'}, Step );
    }
});
$("#forward").click(function(){
    if($slider.position().left >= Max + Step) {
        $slider.animate({left: '-=300px'}, Step );
    }
});
```

Comment: good point, but if I change that I need to change a lot of other things (my code is much more complex)...

Comment: thank you for your effort, I try what you suggested, but is not working, only one time is scrolling...and I have multiple items there.

Answer (score 0):

If you can place entire block out of the screen, you can get the size of the element, for the hidden elements you cant access.

You can use `position:absolute` and keep away from view port